# Using a formula in a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following formula:

```
Range("ZZ1").Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(--(A3:A" & LastRow & "<>""""))"
```

Now I wish I could use it directly to get the value without first putting it on my sheet. 
Is there a way to get it inside a variable directly as below?

```
Dim x as long
x = "=SUMPRODUCT(--(A3:A" & LastRow & "<>""""))"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Evaluate` like this:

```
Dim x as long
x = Application.Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(--(A3:A" & LastRow & "<>""""))")
```

This will evaluate in the context of the active sheet. You can also use the `Worksheet.Evaluate` method to evaluate in the context of a specific sheet.

One caveat: the formula string cannot be longer than 255 characters, but that does not appear to be an issue here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Application.CountIf`:

```
x=Application.Countif(Range("A3:A" & LastRow),"<>"))
```